# Accidentally created directory named "~" (tilde)

Tags: filesystem, directory

I managed to make a directory *literally* named `~`.

(Apparently, Python's `os.mkdir('~/something')` does this.)

How do I remove it without nuking my home?

Also, if it helps, I have my real `/home` on a separate partition. And the duplicate `~` is located in (the *real* ) `~`.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](http://beesbuzz.biz/d/random-every_xkcd_3.php). Ok, I may have lied about it being obligatory. And being an XKCD.

Comment: To answer the Python question you didn't ask, in future, use `os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/something'))`.

Comment: ... just for curiosity, since you created the directory in python didn't you think to do [`os.rmdir('~/something')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rmdir) to delete it?

Comment: @Bakuriu Eventually, I *did* figure that out

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Escape the `~` with `\~` or use single quotes `'~'`.
so you can

```
rmdir ~/\~
```

or

```
cd ~ ; rmdir '~'
```

Comment: If you are worried about deleting something you shouldn't, you could first do something non-destructive like:
    mv '~' normalname, 
then remove the directory normalname.

Comment: `rmdir` is non-destructive. `rmdir` will only delete directories that are empty, so if you try to `rmdir` any directory that has anything at all in it, `rmdir` will refuse to delete it.

Comment: You don't even need to escape the tilde in the first of these commands -- `~` is expanded specially only at the beginning of a shell "word".

Comment: You can even just `rmdir *`. As it only removes empty directories, you don't need to worry about it doing anything destructive.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson: If you want to check your command first, use `ls -d` to see if it lists the directory or file you want it to.  No need for anything with an effect like `mv`.

Answer (score 43):

What python giveth, python taketh away:

```
$ python -c 'import os; os.makedirs("~/foo")'; tree; python -c 'import os; os.removedirs("~/foo")'; tree
.
└── ~
    └── foo

2 directories, 0 files
.

0 directories, 0 files
```

If you did `os.mkdir`, you could undo it with [`os.rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir) (and similarly for `os.makedirs` and `os.removedirs`).

Answer (score 36):

You can either escape the directory name using a backslash like this (assuming you're operating in the parent directory of the one you want to delete):

```
rmdir \~
```

Or you can use relative paths with a dot as the current directory (also when located in the parent directory):

```
rmdir ./~
```

Or you can use the full absolute path:

```
rmdir /home/USERNAME/~
```

---

And no worries, `rmdir` can only remove empty directories. If you accidentally mistype the command and the path would evaluate to your real home directory, it is not in danger because it contains files:

```
$ rmdir directory_with_files
rmdir: failed to remove ‘directory_with_files’: Directory not empty
```

Comment: I like the relative path option.  It should be impossible to map `./~` to `~/`, regardless of which directory you're currently in.  Similar situation with the full absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

`find` command can do such miracles. The command

```
ls -i
```

will give you inode number of files or directory.
Then you can use `find` to delete such files or directory using:

```
find . -inum <inode-number> -delete #for a file
```

and

```
find . -inum <inode-number> -exec rm -rf {}\; #for directories
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What should have been done

You should have performed `home=os.path.expanduser("~")` first and then `os.path.join(home,"something")`. The `~` is treated as text in python and doesn't expand like it does in `bash` or other shells.

```
$ python -c 'import os;home=os.path.expanduser("~"); os.mkdir(os.path.join(home,"something"))'                                                                                          

$ ls -ld ~/something
drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 7月  12 21:00 /home/xieerqi/something/
```

#### How to get rid of it

In addition to the already mentioned methods, we can use hex value for `~` from the ascii table of characters, which unlike actual `~` doesn't expand to user's home directory on command line (In case you're wondering, when tilde appears at the beginning of a word, it expands to user's home directory. Compare `ls ~` and `ls $'\x7e'`).

Here's how it would work:

```
# Make the directory
$ mkdir ./~                                                                                                                                                                             
$ stat ./$'\x7e'                                                                                                                                                                        
  File: './~'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 5768019     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2017-07-12 21:05:31.382828424 -0600
Modify: 2017-07-12 21:05:31.382828424 -0600
Change: 2017-07-12 21:05:31.382828424 -0600
 Birth: -

# and remove it 
$ rmdir ./$'\x7e'                                                                                                                                                                       
$ ls $'\x7e'
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'~'` suffice?