# Open a doc from terminal, but not by its name

Tags: command-line, files, directory

Is it possible to open a file from the terminal not by its name but by its (number) position in the folder? Or any other option?

Because the name is too long.

Comment: Please [edit] and give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: No, not without coding it. But you can use "tab" completion.

Comment: Too long for what?

Comment: Have you tried typing the first two or three letters of the file name and then pressin the `Tab` key?

Answer (score 44):

You probably haven't discovered <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion)) yet.

While typing a filename in Terminal just type a first few letters and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and see magic!

Comment: Or just type the first few letters of the filename, and a `*`, if you don't want to use Tab-completion for some reason. Or even `*abc*` if the filename contains `abc` somewhere (try to use a subpattern that's unique to the filename you want). Or just copy/paste the filename using the mouse.

Comment: @guntram Or you can even drag-and-drop files to Terminal.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm you should make that an answer. I think it is sufficiently different from this answer to stand on its own.

Answer (score 32):

Just for fun, literally answering the question:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

show_hidden = False

currfiles = os.listdir("./")
if not show_hidden:
    currfiles = [f for f in currfiles if not f.startswith(".")]
n = 1
for f in currfiles:
    print(str(n) + ". " + f)
    n = n + 1

picked = int(input("Quick, quick, give me a number:\n"))
subprocess.run(["xdg-open", currfiles[picked - 1]])
```

#### How it works in practice

1. In terminal, in the working dir, run "o" (as a command)
2. The content of the current directory is listed, numbered. Pick the number and the item is opened:

   [image]

#### Set up

...is easy:

1. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, a folder named "bin" in your home directory
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as (literally) "o" (no extension), and ***make it executable***
3. Log out and back in and start using the command by just typing

   ```
   $ o
   ```

   in terminal

#### N.B.

If you'd like to show hidden files as well, change

```
show_hidden = False
```

into:

```
show_hidden = True
```

Comment: If `~/bin` isn't already in your PATH, you'll have to add it (for instance, putting a line like `export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"` into `.bashrc` or `.profile`.)

Comment: See [b0fh's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127828/329506) - this seems to be a built-in from bash

Comment: @kundor nope, not on Ubuntu. Log out and in does the job, or simply `source ~/.profile`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  `~/bin` is not built into anything at all. Ubuntu and Debian ship with custom `~/.profile` that has lines `if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" ; fi`.  On Mac OS X and CentOS  you have to configure that yourself. A good chance is that if Ubuntu is provided to a person by IT department, chances are the `~/.profile` won't be the same as default Ubuntu, so it's a good practice to always beware that `~/bin` is not standard.  Bash also can ignore `~/.profile` if you launch the shell with `--no-profile` option

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Original comment was meant for you, actually ^

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Since I swtitched to Ubuntu (2011), I have always either logged in or ran `source ~/.profile` (always used `~/.bin` for my own scripts to call). It didn't fail on me a single time. Of course if people run altered versions of Ubuntu, things can differ, but in general in an answer we may assume just Ubuntu IMO.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  That's  good, and running `source ~/.profile` or loggin out/in is the proper way. But it is only good enough on stock Ubuntu, and like I said the Ubuntu version that is in use could be provided by IT department or users environment is managed by another administrator.  It's not the question of whether or not it fails or not, we just need to be aware how things *really* work. It helps both the user and us to troubleshoot/post answers.  For instance, if something works in Budgie on Ubuntu but not in Solus.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy True of course, but Solus is not Ubuntu :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Solus is not Ubuntu, but Ubuntu doesn't exist in a vacuum either ;) There's a larger world out there

Comment: @JacobVlijm regarding b0fh's answer, couldn't you just save it in a bash script in the bin folder, same as your answer?

Answer (score 28):

There is a little-known feature in Bash that allows you to do this without calling on python or any other third-party tool, and with a single line:

```
select file in *; do open "$file"; break; done
```

Comment: Excellent! `open` typically won't work, though (unless you're on Mac OS); `xdg-open` will probably do the trick on most GNU/Linux systems.

Comment: But bash is not the only shell in existence, you know :-)

Answer (score 16):

In pure bash, using the `select` statement:

```
PS3='Quick, quick, give a number: '

select file in *
do 
    xdg-open "$file"
    break
done
```

Setting PS3 is just eyecandy. If you leave it out, you will just get the default prompt. If you leave out the break statement, the select statement will loop until you hit CTRL-D or CTRL-C.

Of course you can also run it as a one-liner:

```
select file in *; do xdg-open "$file"; break; done
```

Comment: Simple enough of a solution and works well enough. You can go a step further and make an alias or function out of it

Answer (score 7):

You can install and use **`mc`**, Midnight Commander. It is a text user interface with menus etc inspired by the old Norton Commander, that was popular when people used MSDOS (before Windows).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mc
```

and start it in a terminal window or in a text screen,

```
mc
```

Answer (score 5):

`$ ls`

```
results.log
string
Templates
textfile
time
time.save
vegetables
vegetablesbsh
```

How bout

`ls | sed -n 3p`

Prints *3rd* file name

`Templates`

Open it-

`xdg-open "$(ls | sed -n 3p)"`

Usually works.

Put it in a script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

xdg-open "$(ls | sed -n "$1"p)"
```

Name of script: open

Save it in home folder. 
Run:

```
./open file_number
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 3):

On Linux filesystems, filenames have a very interesting property called [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode): a directory ( or folder ) is a listing of inodes and which filenames point to those inodes. So, if you know the inode number, you can attempt to locate the file using `find` utility and do certain operations on it. This is especially useful when dealing with filenames in different locale, [special characters](https://askubuntu.com/a/984806/295286), or [when you accidentally created directory called `~`](https://askubuntu.com/q/754881/295286).

For example,

```
$ ls -i1
1103993 crs.py
1103743 foobar.txt
1147196 __pycache__
1103739 'with'$'\n''newline.png'
1103740 yellowstone.jpg

$ find . -type f -inum 1103743 -exec xdg-open {} \; -and -quit
```

What this does is traverse current working directory ( represented by `.` ) and look for directory entry that is a file with inode number 1103743. If the file is found, `xdg-open` will open the file with default application and `find` will quit afterwards. The reason for the extra `-and` and `-quit` is to prevent `xdg-open` reopening the file if there exist hard links to the file (which is equivalent to opening the same file twice).

Answer (score 1):

Make some files:

```
$ for i in $(seq -w 0 20); do echo "This is file $i." > $i.txt; done
$ ls
00.txt  03.txt  06.txt  09.txt  12.txt  15.txt  18.txt
01.txt  04.txt  07.txt  10.txt  13.txt  16.txt  19.txt
02.txt  05.txt  08.txt  11.txt  14.txt  17.txt  20.txt
$ cat 16.txt 
This is file 16.
```

Put the files into a variable and open the file by an index.

```
$ files=(*)
$ xdg-open "${files[12]}"
# Opens 12.txt in a text editor, which reads "This is file 12."
```

Replace `12` with the index you're trying to open.

Comment: I'd prefer {00..20} instead of $(seq -w 0 20) because it's just one external process less to spawn. I'm not sure about portability though. Might be a bash-ism.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest answer that directly answers the question.
try the following:

```
touch file-1 file-2 file-3
```

Let's say we want to open (or edit) the second file, we can do the following:

```
echo `ls` | cut -d' ' -f2
```

this will output the name of the second file, which we can use as input to the command we want to perform, for example:

```
cat $( echo `ls` | cut -d' ' -f2 )
```

will output the content of the second file.

> note that you can change the order in which the files are printed by ls, by tweaking ls arguments, see `man ls` for details.

[UPDATE] this assumes that you have no white-spaces in file names,
thanks @wjandrea for your observation.

Comment: This will fail for filenames that contain spaces. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127770/301745) gets around that, but it's still a bad idea to parse `ls`. Also backticks are deprecated. Use `$()` instead.